# Rails Template Inline Code not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a ruby on rails html.erb file with inline code in it like below. However, the code doesn't always run when somebody loads the page. It only prints to stdout the first time the page is loaded.

```
<%puts "TESTING"%>
```

Does rails cache my html.erb pages somehow? Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: You don't need puts, just: <%= "TESTING" %>

Comment: @Rinon: how does one print to stdout without puts? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev , we're talking about Rails Templates. In the answer he says "when somebody loads the page", hence we're talking about views. That's why my conclusion is, he wants to display some data in a view.

Comment: @Rinon: not necessarily. It may be some debug printing. Which may look better in server log.

Comment: @Rinon: also note the "doesn't always run". Which implies that it __does__ sometimes run (and produce desired effect). So the code is not the issue.

Comment: Ofri, clarify your question. Do you really want to print to stdout from views?

Comment: I'm only printing to std out since I want to see that its running every time the page is being loaded.

Comment: I just want to understand what behavior in rails causes the code to not run on every reload of the page. Is there some type of cache that stopes the rails template from being rerun each time the page is loaded

Comment: @OfriHarlev: yeah, most certainly there are caches. But it's hard to tell why exactly does this happen without being able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What could I provide to help reproduce the issue? Is it the standard behavior in rail to cache a template file and is there an easy way to turn it off for a specific template

Comment: @OfriHarlev: ideally I'd want a [mcve]. In this case, a super-stripped down rails app, which I can clone and run. It is very likely that in the process of creating said MCVE, you'll find the answer yourself. I've seen this happen countless times :)

Comment: Also this could be useful: [Caching with Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not sure how I would be able to do that as I can't even reproduce this locally only in a production environment.

Comment: @OfriHarlev: well, in this case, read through the guide and try to locate caching instructions in your code (like `<%= cache ... %>`). I'm pretty sure this must be explicit caching.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output something you need to use `<%=  %>` instead of  `<%  %>`

```
<%= "TESTING" %>
```

- `<%=  %>` - Evaluate and print the output
- `<%  %>` - only evaluate

Comment: 1) If the goal is to render to html, one doesn't need puts. 2) maybe the goal is to print to stdout, in which case `<% puts 'testing' %>` __IS__ the right code.

Comment: ahh.. OP says html.erb so I think <%= "Testing" %> will work

Comment: "OP says html.erb" - so what? There are legitimate reasons why you'd want to print to server log from a view.

Comment: I'm trying to debug which is why im printing to server log in the html. I have a line of code which should generate a new key each time someone visits the page but since the file only runs the first time someone visits the page the key isn't being regenrated

Comment: I can tell that its only being run once since TESTING is only being printed once

Comment: So its not the issue of this line maybe you need to check the method for genaerating the key

Comment: The issue is that when I refresh the page TESTING doesn't get written to std out again

Comment: I will not get offended for a proper explained reason

Comment: This does not answer the question. I retracted it, for now, since you're being active and may change your answer. but it keeps the same, I'll dv again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<%= "TESTING" %>
```

`<%= %>` is used to print the text in html.erb file